# Change dfs.block.size on application execution

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Since dfs.block.size is an HDFS setting, it shouldn't make a difference if I change it during an application execution, right?
For example, if the block size of the files of a job are 128 and I call

```
hadoop jar /path/to/.jar xxx -D dfs.block.size=256
```

would it make a difference or would I need to change the block size before saving the files to HDFS?
Are dfs.block.size and the split size of tasks directly related? If im correct and they are not, is there a way to specify the size of a split?

Answer (score 0):

> Parameters which decides your split Size for each MR can be set by
>
> **mapred.max.split.size    &  mapred.min.split.size**
>
> **"mapred.max.split.size"** which can be set per job individually through
>   your conf Object. Don't change "dfs.block.size" which affects your
>   HDFS too.Which does change your output block size of execution.
>
> if **mapred.min.split.size** is less than block size and 
>   mapred.max.split.size is greater than block size then 1 block is sent
>   to each map task. The block data is split into key value pairs based
>   on the Input Format you use.